# android TV NEXBOX A95X screen orientation portrait

Tags: android, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait, television

I want to display my screen always in portrait mode on TV(NEXBOX A95X). I have set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to Activity on Manifest file. But it is working on mobile devices but not working on TVs. It is displaying horizontally in landscape mode. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would the user want the output to be portrait?

Comment: I would like to put TV in vertical position in order to display more information!

Comment: OK, that sounds reasonable. Unfortunately, I suspect that the device manufacturer did not consider your scenario. My guess is that you will need to contact them to see if there is some workaround.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your response! No solution yet? I have googled many users have the same issue.